# Regex to match all newlines before a word in the file

Tags: regex

OK I give up. I have a alternative for this but I am curious if the the following is possible.

I have an htm file that has newlines before the doctyoe declaration. See below

```
 linefeed and spaces here
 linefeed and spaces here
 <!DOCTYPE html>
```

So I need a regex that can select all that newlinefeed and/or spaces in one shot before the doctype declaration.

Anyone?

Comment: what do you mean by select?  do you need to know how many there are?

Comment: which flavor/implementation of regex do you want to use? Perl, javaScript, Java, php, python?

Answer (score 1):

Following regex should capture that text:

```
(?i)(?s)^(.*?)<!DOCTYPE html>
```

All the text before `DOCTYPE` declaration will be available in group # 1.